# execute maven run on a module during another module phase

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven multi module project, where one of the modules is a (spring based) commandline tool that generate the source code for the other modules.

maven root

- project A
- project B
- project Tool

in project A and B I have some `/src/gen/java` folders whose content is filled by running `mvn spring-boot:run` of the project Tool.

It's possible to teach maven to bind the execution of project tool during the `generate-sources` of project A and B?

Comment: You can bind the execute maven plugin or the spring-boot:run in another module to be bound to a different phase... please show the full example of your project setup...